# Compare inserted date with existing in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create trigger which will check if there is a value in the table with the same time and the same theater id

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCheckSameTime
ON dbo.Poster
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT P.Id_Poster
              FROM Poster P, inserted I
              WHERE P.Date = I.Date AND P.Id_Theater = I.Id_Theater)
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR('There can''t be two spectacles at the same time in the same theater', 16, 10)
    END
```

I'm trying to use this, so I want it when I enter

```
INSERT INTO Poster
VALUES (1,4,1,'20190420 16:00:00')
INSERT INTO Poster
VALUES (1,4,1,'20190420 16:00:00')
```

To trigger forbid it to do, but this trigger prohibits entering any data in the table.

3rd Value in table is theater_id and 4rth is date,

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I think you are looking for an `INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE` trigger her, and then you can `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ....INNER JOIN INERTED ON ... THEN INSERT INTO Poster SELECT * FROM INSERTED`...

Comment: Run `DELETE FROM Poster WHERE Id_Poster = 1` before testing ?

Comment: Did you intend to refuse all simultaneous inserts if one of them is existing?

Comment: Why not solve this by using a constraint?

Comment: Well yes - it's an **AFTER INSERT** trigger, which runs **AFTER** the insert has already happened - so the data / row that is stored in the `Inserted` table will **ALWAYS** already be in the table, of course! Checking that `IF EXISTS()` clause therefore is **ALWAYS** true ......You need to add something else/additional to that check to avoid checking against the row(s) you've just inserted (or updated) in the statement that fired this trigger....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check before the data inserted as

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCheckSameTime
ON dbo.Poster
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Poster P INNER JOIN INSERTED I
         ON P.Id_Theater = I.Id_Theater 
            AND
            P.[Date] = I.[Date]
  )
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Poster(<Columns Here>) 
    SELECT <Columns Here> FROM INSERTED;
  END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR('There can''t be two spectacles at the same time in the same theater', 16, 10)
      END
```

You can also create a `constraint` which is the better solution for your issue.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Poster
ADD CONSTRAINT <Constraint Name Here> UNIQUE(Id_Theater, [Date]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use the constraint.